# Removing Object Item from a List

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview

I want to delete an item when user **longClicked** to selected **RecyclerView** item.
**mWebsite** is an object list with two String values.

***setOnLongClickListener of RecyclerViewAdapter;***

```
holder.cardView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "ITEM: "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            builder2.setTitle("Are you sure to delete this item?");
            builder2.setMessage("'"+mWebsite.get(position).getWebUrl()+"'");


            builder2.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    mWebsite.remove(position);

                }
            });

            builder2.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            });


            builder2.setCancelable(true);
            builder2.create().show();


            return true;
        }
    });
```

**But, I get this error;** *(Line 106 is; mWebsite.remove......)*

```
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:310)
at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: look at your error it is not at Line 106 it is at 310 and have problem getting the data "at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:310)"

Comment: can you show full code

Comment: I think that line causes the error (But please add the Code) builder2.setMessage("'"+mWebsite.get(position).getWebUrl()+"'"); @Salman500 ArrayList.java:310 is a stacktrace element and not the line the error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

adapter.remove(item);
adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);